# Can a location be derived from a compilation of paintings?

Tags: visualization, image-recognition, geospatial

I have added a link to the collected paintings that were put into a video below.

[image]

I apologize for the quality, I had to gif and reduce it to fit here. (The SE team may consider increasing the size accepted), a better video here: [https://www.tiktok.com/@bobrossdailyvids/video/7244965938213309722][2]
After watching the Bob Ross movie and learning about how he spent much of his life in Vermont, USA, I wonder is it possible to use recognition software where this set of painting of this river is based with some degree of accuracy? Some say Alaska but I would like a more precise location.

[2]: https://www.tiktok.com/@bobrossdailyvids/video/7244965938213309722derived compilation